# horizontal bars with vaadein 8

Tags: vaadin8

i very new with Vaadin.

i have a chart with bars veritcally.
i want to geht horizontal bars

i have read here:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/charts/java-api/charts-charttypes.html

thats a part of my source (no errors):

```
    Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.BAR);
    Configuration configuration = junkPerMachineChart.getConfiguration();
    configuration.getChart().setType(ChartType.BAR);
    configuration.addSeries(series);
    junkPerMachineChart.setCaption("Stündlicher Verbrauch Mischer");
    getUI().access(() -> junkPerMachineChart.drawChart());
```

i searched inside my junkPerMachineChart for a method like

.setType(ChartType.Vertical);

there is no option like this.

[image]

i also searched inside the configuration and found no method like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i changed ChartType to COLUMN and the bars are now horizontal

```
    Configuration conf = junkPerMachineChart.getConfiguration();
    conf.getChart().setType(ChartType.COLUMN);
```